# How to prevent Angular directive normalization?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm new to Angular so trying to get to grips with it. One early gripe is that the directive is hyphen-ated when used as an html element, and camelCased in the Javascript definition.

For example this Javascript:

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {
   ...etc
```

Correlates to this html:

```
<my-directive></my-directive>
```

I really dislike the fact that the same directive is formatted completely differently. Searching for use of it across my codebase now involves 2 searches.

Ironically I'd like to normalize these two formats. Is there a way of configuring my setup so that the html and the Javascript definition both use the same case?

Comment: I don't think so. If you want to avoid all this madness, just use React before it's too late :) If it adds any credibility to my suggestion, I use to be one of the greatest Angular fanboys of all time, but I was wrong.

Comment: i like just put all in lower case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angular is opinionated about many things, including this one. This behaviour [is hardcoded](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.4/src/ng/compile.js#L1491), and normalization cannot be overriden.

Angular has its reasons to force directive names to be camel-cased, because camel case is used as the convention for naming services, and `myDirective` directive becomes `myDirectiveDirective` service internally.

Apparently, `:-_` characters [are used as delimiters](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.4/src/jqLite.js#L136) for normalizing to camel case. While none of them are valid in [HTML element name](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#tag-name), `-` is [the only future-proof](http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/#concepts) delimiter for custom elements among them.

While being convention-breaking, validator-outraging and potentially invalid, any other delimiters can be used, as long as browsers are ok with them. E.g. dot symbol has good chances to do the trick

```
<my.directive></my.directive>
```

in modern browsers.

Breaking Angular's conventions right from the start isn't the best way to make friends with it, the best thing the one could do is to deal with it and to search for `my-?directive` regexp instead, as long as development tools got the support for searching regexps.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't. It's done this way because the DOM is not case sensitive.

But you should quickly get used to it.

Regards,
Eric

Comment: I take your point, but that wouldn't have precluded Angular from allowing us to use the hyphenated format in the Javascript declaration. Appreciate the answer all the same.